# How do you get the client calling URL from ServiceStack Service base class?

Tags: servicestack

I need to log the requesting (client) URL for each request to the service.
I looked through the Request object on the Service base class and the only URL recorded is the service URL requested.  Where can I get the requesting caller URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the context of the request in your `base.Request` and `base.Response` properties in your `Service` class, e.g:

```
var requestUrl = base.Request.AbsoluteUri;
var referrerUrl = base.Request.UrlReferrer;
```

Comment: I realized my question was silly.  There really isn't a requesting URL.  In my particular case a web site is accessing the service so I thought I could get the requesting URL which does not make sense.  I will just have to pass in the requesting application as a property of the request object.

Comment: @BrettMathe You may be referring to the Referral Url? Which you can access with `base.Request.UrlReferrer`